# Cancelación de eco

Tags: audio, audio-manager, puredata

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación que usa el micrófono, y me encuentro con un eco. Todos los ejemplos que encontré de `acousticEchoCanceler` usan una variable que llaman `microphoneId`, algo así:

```
AcousticEchoCanceler acousticEchoCanceler=AcousticEchoCanceler.create(microphoneId);
acousticEchoCanceler.setEnabled(true);
```

Pero no encuentro de dónde sale esa variable. ¿Ideas?

PD: El proyecto funciona con un patch de Pure Data.

Comment: Ya intenté deviceInfo[0].getId() e intenté con todos los números de 0 a 50, y siempre me sale el mismo error: `2020-02-29 14:05:59.322 13816-13816/com.example.beltingphone E/AudioEffect: set(): AudioFlinger could not create effect, status: -22
2020-02-29 14:05:59.322 13816-13816/com.example.beltingphone E/AudioEffects-JNI: AudioEffect initCheck failed -3
2020-02-29 14:05:59.322 13816-13816/com.example.beltingphone E/AudioEffect-JAVA: Error code -3 when initializing AudioEffect.
2020-02-29 14:05:59.323 13816-13816/com.example.beltingphone W/AcousticEchoCanceler: not enough memory`

Comment: Me olvidé de decir que también intenté con los números del 0 al 10 en el array deviceInfo.

Comment: Descubrí que el objeto se crea, pero el problema empieza cuando le doy setEnabled; incluso si le doy false.

Comment: Siguiendo un concejo, intenté usar STREAM_VOICE_CALL en lugar de echocanceler, pero no noto ninguna diferencia.

Comment: Intenté crear un loop: `while (acousticEchoCanceler==null) { acousticEchoCanceler = AcousticEchoCanceler.create(i); i++; Log.i("msg", ""+i); }` 

Llega hasta 548 y me da un un error "EOF".